# Descarregar Array Javascript em um Combobox

Tags: javascript, html, array, combobox

Gostaria da ajuda nesse pequeno problema, tenho que fazer um combobox mostra 5 estados sendo carregado por um array em javascript, meu código está assim.

HTML

```
<select >
    <option id="estado"></option>
</select>
```

Meu Javascript está assim

```
var select = document.getElementById("estado"); 
var options = ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Paraná", "Pernambuco", "Rio Grande do Sul"]; 

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        //console.log(el);
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
```

Debugando no console.log ele trás os resultados bonitinhos como deve ser.
Mas na hora de printar o objeto ele trás o seguinte erro.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O id deveria estar no `select` e não no `option`.

De qualquer maneira o código atual não deveria apresentar o erro que você mostrou, isso parece mais um problema com a ordem das coisas, ou seja, verifique se não está chamando o `script` antes da criação dos elementos, isso é um erro bem comum.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("estado"); 
var options = ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Paraná", "Pernambuco", "Rio Grande do Sul"]; 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="estado">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Então eu executei aqui no stack e deu certo porém no meu código continua o mesmo erro, que coisa.

Comment: Então não deve existir nenhum elemento com id `estado`.

Comment: Achou o problema @AlisonPaulo?

Comment: Então eu acho que sim, mas não estou encontrando um meio de resolver. Por exemplo o html e o js estão separados, o ids estão iguais, o que acho que o html não está fazendo a requisição, não sei se tenho que fazer algum evento para enviar o id para o js

Comment: Isso não faz muito sentido. Ou eu entendi tudo errado.

Comment: O javascript não está sendo executado antas da criação dos elementos, né? Pode ser este o problema.

Comment: olha os códigos estão exatamente como a sua resposta, se eu debugo com o cosole.log sem printar select.appendChild(el); ele mostra os 5 estados, mas quando printo select.appendChild(el); ele da o erro. Isso que não estou entendendo.

Comment: O javascript não está sendo executado antes da criação do HTML?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, que droga perdi 2 horas atoa. Estava fazendo a chamada no head, mudei o local da chamada deu certo. Vlw ai irmão obrigado mesmo.

Comment: existe alguma diferença em usar .appendChild ou .add?